# Porque é que só um select é que fica preenchido?

Tags: php

Bom, é o seguinte o que pretendo é mostrar todas as equipas, de uma tabela, nessa tabela cada linha corresponde a uma equipa. Contudo o que queria fazer era mostrar 1 `<select>` por cada equipa, ou seja, se tiver 4 equipas na BD quero 4 `<select>` e cada um com as 4 equipas para escolher.

Estou com um problema que só um dos `<select>` é que fica preenchido.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O meu código é o seguinte:

```
<?php
$procura3 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * from $tabelatorneio");

while($contador < 4){
?>
    <select>
<?php
    while($array3 = mysqli_fetch_array($procura3)){
?>
        <option value="<?php echo $array3["nomeequipa"]; ?>">
            <?php echo $array3["nomeequipa"]; ?>
        </option>
<?php
    }
?>
    </select>
<?php
    $contador ++;
}
?>
```

O que fiz de errado, para apenas só mostrar 1 select com todas as equipas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema que o fetch já foi feito todo para primeira inteiração. Na segunda vez que passa no laço do contador, mysqli_fetch_array retorna falso, por todas as linhas de $procura3 já foram lidas. É preciso refazer a consulta.

```
<?php

while($contador < 4) {
  $procura3 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * from $tabelatorneio");
?>

<select>
<?php while($array3 = mysqli_fetch_array($procura3)){ ?>
  <option value="<?= $array3["nomeequipa"]; ?>"><?= echo $array3["nomeequipa"]; ?></option>
<?php } // fecha while do fetch ?>
</select>
<?php
 $contador ++;
} //fecha while do contador ?>
```

Comment: O erro continua, porem agora, só aparecem 4 inputs mas sem os nomes das equipas de futebol.

Comment: Já Consegui!, Obrigado.

Comment: Substitui <?= por <?php echo

Comment: Se eu quiser atribuir um input text a cada dois selects como posso fazer?